# Non static method cannot be refrence as a static method

Tags: android

```
I just want to create drawable using color.
```

so i use this method  `Drawable background =   Drawable.setColorFilter( 0xffff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );`
here is my full code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.taketestactivity);
    Drawable background =   Drawable.setColorFilter( 0xffff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
    }
```

Comment: Thats not how you specify colors in Android. You need to put that hex into colors.xml as an asset resource and reference it from your activity via the resource file R. Also your title doesnt appear to match your question.

Comment: It's an instance method, not a static method. Call it on a Drawable.

Answer (score 1):

setColorFilter is a method of the Drawable class. 
So after you declare background as a Drawable, then you can write:

```
background.setColorFilter( 0xffff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```